# Regular expression to match 0-2 characters followed by 4 digits

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to make a regular exp for C#. The 1st two letters are characters which are optional and then 4 digits which are mandatory.
as:

```
4584
0259
0015
G3227
G3277
G4018
G3737
G3737
G3277
GU4444
GU4444
G3277
G3277
G3988
C3737
G3227
G3227
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest this:

```
\b\p{L}{0,2}\d{4}\b
```

This would be for finding text like this in a larger string. If you want to validate a string instead, use

```
^\p{L}{0,2}\d{4}$
```

Comment: +1 for Unicode support. Though the OP likely doesn't need it, you might consider discussing `\p{Nd}` or `\p{N}` in place of `\d`, also.

Comment: If the string ending with C1, or C2 ....
EX 
GU4444C1
GU4444C3
G3277C2
G3277C4
G3988

so can u help me?

Comment: Just add `(?:C\d)?` before the final delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{0,2}\d{4}$
```

Comment: You need to anchor your regex or it will match `321_AhVg1234hhd`

Comment: Also you don't need the square brackets around `\d`.